# stm32 timers: starts and resets on same trigger

Tags: stm32

I has a periodic signal (22 kHz square), connected to IC1 of TIM3. I need to measure a duration of this signal.
Current realisation is:
1. TIM2 is programmed as one-pulse, arr = signal period + little deviation, trigger mode slave, with CEN as master output, trigger INT  enabled.
2. in TIM2 ISR just do TIM2->CNT = 0;
3. TIM3 is slave timer in gated mode, connected to tim2. trigger INT enabled.
4. in TIM3 ISR just count a diffrence current CNT and prev CNT to meas  ure a signal duration.
It is works, but times is not 100% accurate due to ISR calling & execution time.
Questions:
1. Can i use same external event for starting AND reseting same timer?
2. Can i use input capure registers in my realisation?
3. Some better ideas for my task?
i'm realy break my brains for a days. Please help... ;-)

Comment: Definitely - just use the input capture mode.

Answer (score 0):

@P__J__ is right - you should configure and use the input capture mode many timers on STM32 offer you. Then you won't need any ISR (software) in the moments when the signal flanks are recognized because the MCU will do that for you. You'll only need some software to read out the measurements from the Input Capture, but you'll be more or less free to do this in ISR or poll from main program.

The `TIMx` peripherals are pretty complex.
Therefore, I suggest to have a look at
[this Application Note from ST](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00236305-generalpurpose-timer-cookbook-for-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf)
as well as
[that one](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00042534-stm32-crossseries-timer-overview-stmicroelectronics.pdf).